# What are some RCP Deployment Options?

Tags: deployment, installation, rcp

We have an RCP application and we are looking for a better way to do installation/updates. Currently to install, they just unzip a zip file.  The zip file also contains scripts in it that are not java code.  We were running into some bugs when updating if they don't first delete the old folder that was previous unzipped. The issue with deleting the folder is that the user loses the plugin preferences that were set.  The installation would also need to register a COM server. The update would have to update the plugins and also replace the current script folder. What are some of the best options that could be used for installing and updating rcp apps? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use the eclipse update mechanism. In this case the user would simply update like in the eclipse ide using help->software update. I have not used it myself yet ,but I have visited a tutorial from kai tödter, just google "eclipse rcp adanced kai tödter" und you will find some stuff, e.g. slides where he explains the updated mechanism as well as an example project "MP3 Manager" where you can find an example